# Detecting when a value changes in a @ViewChild()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I have been provided with a component which is simply a +/- counter. I can get a reference to the value I need from this component like this:

```
<sas-plus-minus value="0" min="0" max="99" #adultCount></sas-plus-minus>
{{ adultCount.val }}
```

`adultCount.val` displays the correct value from the `sas-plus-mins` component, but I don't know how to watch for changes in this value within the parent component. It would be quite difficult for me to modify this child component's code, in which I would probably use an `Output()` to notify the parent of the change.

How can I register a wathcer in my parent component for this `sas-plus-minus`'s `val`?

Comment: You can't avoid an event emitter. Either by an `@Output` or a `Subject`, but you will have to rely on events.

Comment: why can not edit you component code ??? you should right ?

Answer (score -1):

You can put a listener on this:

```
<sas-plus-minus (change)="detect($event)" value="0" min="0" max="99" #adultCount [(ngModel)]="adultCount"></sas-plus-minus>
```

If (change) doesnot work put (ngModelChange) instead. And in your .ts file:

```
detect(event){console.log(event);}
```

And you can derive value from event.